# Is it possible to have a count based on another count?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that counts answers that do not meet certain criteria. Here is the formula: `=COUNTA(K3:K325)-SUM(COUNTIF(K3:K325,"*" & {"Not Interested","Career Link","OVR","VBA","No Show","Vet Canceled"} & "*"))` I have a second formula that counts the answer for Support Ed, during October: `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$H$3:H$325,"Support Ed",Referrals!$A$3:$A$325,"<"&'Month Source'!K7)`(10/31/16), & one for the other 11 months, `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$H$3:$H$325,"Support Ed",Referrals!$A$3:$A$325,">="&'Month Source'!L6,Referrals!$A$3:$A$325,"<="&'Month Source'!L7)`(11/30/16)I am trying to count the number of times that an answer does not match the above text, during a month.

Comment: Are there more criteria in your list of data or do your 3 formulas catch them all? Do you want to include blank cells (if there are any) in your "does not match above text" count?

Comment: The first formula catches the responses, & the two other formulas catch the month. I am trying to replace Support Ed with the response from the first formula.

Comment: Are you trying to count something or to replace something? Two very different problems!

Comment: I am trying to count something. The number of times that an answer other than **Not Interested, Career Link, OVR, VBA, No Show, Vet Canceled** occurs during a given month.

Answer (score 1):

To count everything in your range but certain values, you just need to modify the counting formula you already have. I gathered that your data is always comprised in rows 3 to 325 so wrote the formula accordingly. I also suggest that you create a list of the elements you want to count (or in this case *not* count) as it makes it easier to add or delete elements from a list than go in every formula you have:

```
=ROW(K325)-2-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(K3:K325,"*" & Named_List & "*"))
```

I'm not sure how your data is arranged by month so I couldn't add that, but you seem to have figured out that part already. You can probably use what you already have for other formulas with this one.

Comment: I found an answer that is very simple, because of your assistance. `=IF(B13-B16-B19-B22-B25-B28-B31<0, 0, B13-B16-B19-B22-B25-B28-B31)` The various cell locations are for the text that was mentioned previously.